# Is cat files slower if run through bash file and screen?

Tags: bash, sorting, cat

I am doing

```
cat this_files_* > output.txt # reads approx 20 mio. files and cats them into output.txt
```

When doing it through command-line last week on another dataset, it was significantly faster than it is now run through a bash file main.sh.

Is it possible that cat through bash file is slower/limited?

Also - suggestions on doing this faster welcome! (Bash or Python)
The main reason why I am doing it through cat is because of RAM issues with other options, and it just seems easier. (after this, I run: `sort output.txt > output_sorted.txt`)

Comment: It shouldn't make any diffference whether you do it interactively or from a script. The terminal isn't involved when executing the command.

Comment: There are better ways to generate a large sorted file with a lot of smaller files as inputs. `sort` supports, in particular, a very efficient merge support mode.

Comment: (But no, whether it's being run from a bash script or via a terminal makes no difference at all)

Comment: I suggest: `sort this_files_* > output_sorted.txt`

Comment: what @Cyrus said above -- and be sure you're using GNU sort, with a TMPDIR that's backed by real disk, not RAM; that way it can write temporary files to disk when there's no memory available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### **No.**

When `sort` is not reading from stdin, writing to stdout, or actively sending error messages to stderr, it does depend on terminal performance.

Similarly, it never inspects its parent process, so it doesn't know or care if it was started by a shell or any other process.

---

That said, using `cat` makes your code unnecessarily inefficient.

```
sort this_files_* >output_sorted.txt
```

...still requires an amount of working space that scales with the size of your files -- as is also required in the `cat` case -- but as long as you're using a high-quality `sort` implementation such as the GNU one, it can use temporary files for storage and so sort contents larger than RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution and the explanation! Did not know that sort offers a direct combination in bash. Hope that this speeds things up a little.

Comment: (To be clear, `sort` can still use temporary files when it's getting input from a pipe, but knowing its input files lets it be more efficient; with real files, one can have different threads reading different parts in parallel, can do reads out-of-order, &c; whereas with a pipe, content can only be read exactly once front-to-back)